# Why does my image disappear after a very small decrement?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

I want to convert this to black and white at small increments, the strange thing is that it just disappears after one increment.

For this line

```
bw_normal = im2bw(img, 0.33);
```

I get this:

[image]

But for this line:

```
bw_normal = im2bw(img, 0.32);
```

The word disappears entirely, this shouldn't happen right? It only happens with this image, any other image will continue to show up until 0.1.

This is what I get at `0.32`

[image]

Just a white space, can anyone please explain this.

Comment: You might get the effect that you want with imerode operator, this will gradually make the text disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`im2bw` converts the image to a binary (black/white) image. It does this by comparing all pixels' luminance component to the threshold value you provide as the second argument. If the pixel is brigther, it is made white, if it's darker, it is made black.

In your case, the image has only one color (pretty much). This color has a luminance component between `0.32` and `0.33`, so if you use `0.33` as threshold, most of the colored portion of the image will be below the threshold and be made black. If you use `0.32`, however, most if not all of the image will be above the threshold and thus be made white.

What you experience is expected behavior since your image is basically white background and a single color for the foreground. Once your "increment" reaches that color's luminance, your image is gone.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @scenia. But unfortunately I have to work on the image at ``0.1`` threshold. How do I make it so that it lasts even till the ``0.1`` value? And do that without converting it to binary as I have to perform ``im2bw`` on the image obtained after the ``0.1`` threshold.

Comment: @Faraz what exactly do you want to do with the image using this threshold? If you want to perform `im2bw` on it after applying the threshold, what is the threshold supposed to achieve? As it is right now, if you want it to remain until `0.1`, you would need to change the color to a darker one. Are you trying to gradually convert the image to grayscale, then to binary?

Comment: I basically need the text to survive until ``0.1``. As at ``0.1`` it is supposed to be hundreds of points. It is that image that I require. For example this image: http://imgur.com/fshNUjC when thresholded at this value will present the word as a collection of points. So basically how do I make the "Adams" word picture similar to the Arabic one I just showed? Thank you

Comment: The image is already a collection of points. They're just connected because there are so many. If you want to statically force a threshold of `0.1`, you must change the picture's color. You could convert it to luminance/chrominance using `rgb2ntsc`, then determine the `median` of the luminance column (the first column) and subtract it from each point, then add `0.1`. This will just darken the image. But I think what you're trying to achieve can be better done in a different way. I just still don't really understand what exactly your final goal is...